# Integrate Qunit PhantomJS Maven AMDJS

Tags: maven, phantomjs, qunit

I tried to setup js unit testing, using qunit, phantomjs, maven. The reference I have used for this was: http://kennychua.net/blog/running-qunit-tests-in-a-maven-continuous-integration-build-with-phantomjs

While running (**mvn test**) the test I always gets an error:  `Failed to execute goal net.kennychua:phantomjs-qunit-runner:1.0.15:test (default) on project venus-scripting: One or more QUnit tests failed`

I am using AMD for JS modules. The error message in the output xml is,

```
Error: Cannot find module './test,jquery,qunit'  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require  /home/developer/test/scripting/src/test/js/testTest.js:14
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define  /home/developer/test/scripting/src/main/js/test.js:13
```

I think the below line in my js is the issue:

```
/*global define*/
define("test", [ "jquery" ], function($) {
```

and:

```
/*global require */
require([ "./test", "jquery", "qunit" ], function(TestSrc, $, QUnit) {
```

To work the unit test using *mvn test*, do I need to add the dependency AMD (`require`, `define`) in the `pom.xml`? If that is the case how can I add the dependency to  the maven pom? By the way I have a parent pom and a child pom for the scripting module.